# Need to wrap url inside lightning card

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am using lightning:formattedUrl to show the url.

I don't want give label to this url, so the url should show iin raw format.

However I am using it in card, and it is going beyond the card boundary.

[image: Links]

```
                                <lightning:card title="Microsite Links" iconName="standard:link" variant="base" class="slds-card_boundary">
                                <div class="slds-card__body_inner">

                                    <label lightning-input_input="" for="input-25" class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex">Employer Microsite Link</label>   
                                    <br/>
                                    <lightning:formattedUrl class="slds-truncate" value="{!v.companyEditField.Employer_Microsite_Link__c}" />
                                    <br/>
                                    <label lightning-input_input="" for="input-25" class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex">Employee Microsite Link</label>   
                                    <br/>
                                    <lightning:formattedUrl class="slds-truncate" value="{!v.companyEditField.Employee_Microsite_Link__c}" />
                                </div>
                            </lightning:card>
```

I have tried slds-wrap and slds-truncate on lightning:formattedUrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the slds-truncate on the parent element instead:

```
<div class="slds-card__body_inner slds-truncate">
```

Everything else should work just fine with this change.

Here's an [example in LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/1oCxTlA4h/1/edit), but the principle is the same for Aura.

Comment: Thanks Brian.. it worked :)